# Resample or aggregate large raster limiting memory use R

Tags: r, memory, raster, ram

I'm trying to resample a huge worldpop population raster but I keep crashing my linux instance of R which has 32GB memory. When I launch a 52gb memory google compute instance, the code below works, but it crashes my regular 32gb ram computer.

Is there a way to do either a raster aggregation or resampling LIMITING MEMORY USE?

Download code for a large worldpop raster that I am having issues resampling:

```
###download the huge raster to recreate scale problem
devtools::install_github("nbarsch/spaceheater")
library(spaceheater)
getWPdownload("Tanzania","Population","adj",2015) #warning: downloads near 1gb file
library(raster)
wpras <- raster("TANZANIA_Population_adj_2015.tif")
```

TWO METHODS that work on a computer with 52GB ram, but kill my local computer 32GB ram:

```
#aggregate method
agras <- raster::aggregate(wpras,fact=10,expand=T)
#returns "Killed"

#resamp method
reras <- raster(nrow = ceiling(nrow(wpras)/10), ncol = ceiling(ncol(wpras)/10))
reras2 <- raster::resample(wpras, reras, method="bilinear")
#returns Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.3 Gb
```

Anyone have a solution that doesn't use all the ram? Thanks!

Comment: # increase ram
memory.limit()

Answer (score 1):

You probably should update the raster package. The previous short-lived release (2.7-15) had an error in the memory settings. Version 2.8-4 should have fixed that.